# Does MCPE for iOS use up data? If so, how much?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My family's data plan is continuously running out of data over and over again. My mom says it's because I'm playing on MCPE too much, but I'm not really sure if someone else is causing this problem.

Also, in case you need it, I'm in version 1.4.2 of MCPE for iOS.

Comment: The first thing we'd need to know is if you're playing on a local world or a server?

Comment: You can also see how much data you are using by following these instructions https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201299

Comment: I play on local worlds only.

Comment: @FoxMcCloud You should make that an answer.  The OP can check how much data MCPE is using to verify for himself if that's where it's all going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to view how much data you are using that isn't game specific, but [iOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201299) specific.

To see how much cellular data that you've used, go to Settings, then tap Cellular or Mobile Data. If you're using an iPad, you might see Settings > Cellular Data instead.

To see how much cellular data an app is using, scroll down to find the app. If you don't want an app to use cellular data, you can turn it off for that app. When cellular data is off, apps use Wi-Fi for data.

To see the cellular data usage for individual System Services, go to Settings, then tap Cellular or Mobile Data. Then scroll to the bottom of the screen and tap System Services. Cellular data can't be turned on or off for individual System Services.

Depending on your carrier, you may see overall cellular data usage displayed on this screen. If you don’t have this option, or have questions about your data usage, contact your carrier.